# Fatal error trying to convert

Tags: java, eclipse, плагин, minecraft, bukkit-api

Писал плагин для craftbukkit и столкнулся с ошибкой `Fatal error trying to convert`

Я только учусь и подробной информации не нашел

Версия 1.14.4

Главный класс:

```
package SuperPlugin.main;



import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ShapedRecipe;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class plugin_main extends JavaPlugin {
    
    
    
    
    public void onEnable() {
        
        File config = new File(getDataFolder() + File.separator + "config.yml");
        if(!config.exists()) {
            getLogger().info("Creating folders and configuration files");
            getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
            saveDefaultConfig();
        }
        
        
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Handler(),this);
        getCommand("info").setExecutor(new commands(this));
        getCommand("heal").setExecutor(new CommandsHeal(this));
        
        craft();
    }
    public void onDisable() {
        
    }
    private void craft() {
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.ENDER_EYE);
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Телепортер");
        List<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();
        lore.add("Эндер-телепорт");
        meta.setLore(lore);
        meta.addEnchant(Enchantment.DAMAGE_ALL, 3, true);
        item.setItemMeta(meta);
        
        ShapedRecipe s = new ShapedRecipe(item);
        s.shape(new String[] {"A A"," B ","A A"});
        s.setIngredient('A', Material.ENDER_PEARL);
        s.setIngredient('B', Material.ENDER_EYE);
        Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(s);
        
    }

}
```

`plugin.yml`

```
name: SuperPlugin
main: SuperPlugin.main.plugin_main
author: Drimgo
version: 1.0
api-version: 1.13

commands:
    info:
        description: "info about player"
        usage: /info <player>
    heal:
        description: "heal player"
        usage: /heal
```

Вот 3 предупреждения:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Name of automatic module 'craftbukkit' is unstable, it is derived from the module's file name.  module-info.java    /SuperPlugin/src    line 2  Java Problem
The constructor ShapedRecipe(ItemStack) is deprecated   plugin_main.java    /SuperPlugin/src/SuperPlugin/main   line 52 Java Problem
The method getPlayer(String) from the type Bukkit is deprecated commands.java   /SuperPlugin/src/SuperPlugin/main   line 29 Java Problem
```

Comment: А где это сообщение возникает? Возможно вы используете вещи из старого API вот он и ругается